# How to remove or hide the GRUB boot menu in elementary OS?

Tags: grub, startup

I installed another distro to second drive, and later removed it. Now when I boot, I get grub prompt with 30 sec choosing time. It didn't happen with fresh elementary install, bootloader didn't even flash, it went straight to elementary. I want that back, how?

Comment: Will you please try my answer and let me know :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. I'm sure that would work, but I already switched to UEFI-style boot with no bootloader

Answer (score 2):

**To not see the GRUB menu while booting:**

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change `GRUB_TIMEOUT` value  to `0` which is 10 by default.

Now run `sudo update-grub`

Now `reboot`.

*Note*:

If then you need to change to Recovery mode in some instance just press `ESC` when elementary starts. Then the GRUB menu will appear giving you the change to select the recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any Ubuntu based distribution, then it should support PPAs. You could install "grub-customiser". A Google search would help you out.

Other way round is modifying the configuration files. This is explained well on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry). I would not like to copy it as it is well written.

Grub-customiser would be easier to do the task.